# Edit information in database use ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need edit info in database table on the web-page. But I have trouble, data in TextArea not change.
First: display data for change in TextArea.
Secondly: save changes data.
This my C# code

```
 public partial class Edit : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
    Model1 context = new Model1();
    string str;
    int ID;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        str = Request.QueryString["Id"];
        ID = Convert.ToInt32(str);

        FirstArea2.Value = EditQuestion().name;
        editor.Value = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(EditQuestion().details.ToString());
    }
    protected void Send_Click_Save(object sender, EventArgs a)
    {
        EditQuestion().name = FirstArea2.Value;
        EditQuestion().details = editor.Value;
        context.SaveChanges();
        Response.Redirect("FirstPage.aspx");
    }
    public questions2 EditQuestion()
    {
        questions2 question = (from x in context.questions2
                               where x.id == ID
                               select x).FirstOrDefault();
        return question;
    }
}
```

And HTML

```
<textarea id="FirstArea2" name="FirstArea" runat="server" style="width:57.5%;height:16px;" required="required"></textarea>
<textarea id="editor" runat="server" style="width:60%;height:200px;" required="required"> </textarea>
  <asp:Button ID="Save" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="Send_Click_Save"  />
```

Comment: **I need edit info in database table on the web-page. But I have trouble, data in TextArea not change.** << I am clueless about this statement

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to read a few tutorials on Entity framework, for example: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/update-entity-using-dbcontext.aspx

Each time you call EditQuestion() you will get the latest version of the question from the database.
I would suggest something like the following code to update your question2 object.

```
using(var context = new Model1())
{
    questions2 question = (from x in context.questions2
                           where x.id == ID
                           select x).FirstOrDefault();
    if(question != null){ 
       question.name = newName;
       question.details = newDetails;
   }
   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about how works your code, with :

```
  EditQuestion().name = FirstArea2.Value;
  EditQuestion().details = editor.Value;
  context.SaveChanges();
```

You load *two* different instances of question, and you change their values. The first one is lost when you load the second. It's not what you want.

Instead you can do something like :

```
using(var context = new Model1()) // avoid to instantiate context at the page load, it's better to keep it short lived
{
   questions2 question = context.questions2.FirstOrDefault(q => q.id == ID); // this does the same as your code but it's shorter

   if (question != null)
   { 
      question.name = newName;
      question.details = newDetails;
   }
   else
   { // handle insert if needed }

   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

In your page load you do the same kind of mistake, your EditQuestion() method is a bad practice, even for reading data, because it involves an useless access to database at every call.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem! If you are interested:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        str = Request.QueryString["Id"];
        ID = Convert.ToInt32(str);
        if (!IsPostBack)
            { 
        FirstArea2.Value = EditQuestion().name;
        editor.Value =System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(EditQuestion().details.ToString());
            }
     }
```

Thanks for your answers